# How to call Vue Js component methods in same component template attribute?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

My component will looks like the following

**Customer.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="customer-container" class="customer-container">
      <div class="form__row">
        <label class="form__label">test</label>
        <textarea v-on:blur="updateIssue()" class="form_textarea"  id="customerIssue" ref="customerIssue" rows="4" v-model="customer.issue" placeholder="{{cIssuePlaceholder()}}"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Customer.vue - Js part**

```
 methods: {
    titleStr: function () {
      return titleStr
    },
    cIssuePlaceholder: function () {
      return 'placeholder'
    }
 }
```

Here My questions is how can i call the **cIssuePlaceholder()** in my **placeholder** attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is:

> Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use `v-bind` or the colon shorthand instead.

Also, [per docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes):

> Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a `v-bind` directive.

So, instead of `placeholder="{{cIssuePlaceholder()}}"`,

**use** ([shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand))**:**

```
:placeholder="cIssuePlaceholder()"
```

**or:**

```
v-bind:placeholder="cIssuePlaceholder()"
```

Comment: Now how do you pass component variables to this function?

Comment: How about `v-bind:placeholder="cIssuePlaceholder(myComponentVariable)"`?